# SQL - Get PDF items that do NOT have a matching PNG item. Or maybe get PDF items with no PNG item

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of metadata about attachments. Sometimes the auto PDF conversion does not work and it does not create a PNG file. I want a query I can run to see which PDF files this is happening on so I can go fix it..

In this case I want the results:

```
EBE71C1C-643C-48F3-985C-9F369AC08D9F    FW_-[EXTER214627673.pdf
F19EC965-F283-4DFD-9C8C-C20E77987986    Maria-Kim-215001342.pdf
```

So the query to list ALL attachment metadata is

```
SELECT tf.id, tf.CreatedOn, a.FileName
FROM TrainingForm tf
INNER JOIN Attachment a ON tf.Id = a.FormId
ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC
```

and results are like..

```
EBE71C1C-643C-48F3-985C-9F369AC08D9F    FW_-[EXTER214627673.pdf
2DAA9CD3-72C2-4534-A56B-3CE8F57EF61F    ABA-Conf.-211722906.pdf
2DAA9CD3-72C2-4534-A56B-3CE8F57EF61F    ABA-Conf.-2117229061.png
2DAA9CD3-72C2-4534-A56B-3CE8F57EF61F    Tatham-Rec213220321.pdf
2DAA9CD3-72C2-4534-A56B-3CE8F57EF61F    Tatham-Rec2132203211.png
2DAA9CD3-72C2-4534-A56B-3CE8F57EF61F    Tatham-Rec2132203212.png
2DAA9CD3-72C2-4534-A56B-3CE8F57EF61F    Tatham-Rec2132203213.png
2DAA9CD3-72C2-4534-A56B-3CE8F57EF61F    Tatham-Rec2132203214.png
2DAA9CD3-72C2-4534-A56B-3CE8F57EF61F    Tatham-Rec2132203215.png
2DAA9CD3-72C2-4534-A56B-3CE8F57EF61F    Tatham-Rec2132203216.png
297A98DF-E026-45D6-90B3-7935B17A267C    Marina-Con215227983.jpg
297A98DF-E026-45D6-90B3-7935B17A267C    Payment-Re210605370.pdf
297A98DF-E026-45D6-90B3-7935B17A267C    Payment-Re2106053701.png
297A98DF-E026-45D6-90B3-7935B17A267C    Payment-Re2106053702.png
5BB4D0AB-A8B9-436D-BDDB-00929A401F63    Receipt215800891.pdf
5BB4D0AB-A8B9-436D-BDDB-00929A401F63    Receipt2158008911.png
5BB4D0AB-A8B9-436D-BDDB-00929A401F63    Receipt2158008912.png
5BB4D0AB-A8B9-436D-BDDB-00929A401F63    Receipt2158008913.png
5BB4D0AB-A8B9-436D-BDDB-00929A401F63    onepagethi215843940.pdf
5BB4D0AB-A8B9-436D-BDDB-00929A401F63    onepagethi2158439401.png
F19EC965-F283-4DFD-9C8C-C20E77987986    Maria-Kim-215001342.pdf
F19EC965-F283-4DFD-9C8C-C20E77987986    Kim-Receip210738424.pdf
F19EC965-F283-4DFD-9C8C-C20E77987986    Kim-Receip2107384241.png
3DFBBCED-D8A7-4598-9680-D9A199621D18    Watershed-212950831.pdf
3DFBBCED-D8A7-4598-9680-D9A199621D18    Watershed-2129508311.png
3DFBBCED-D8A7-4598-9680-D9A199621D18    Watershed-213024234.pdf
3DFBBCED-D8A7-4598-9680-D9A199621D18    Watershed-2130242341.png
3DFBBCED-D8A7-4598-9680-D9A199621D18    Watershed-2130242342.png
```

EDIT 1:
There is a case where the rename back to original name is not working. It seems to be in the case where the appended number goes two digits. Here is the raw data.

```
8DF92926-20A9-4BE8-A11A-0BCB2B868A31    2021-07-27 16:42:13.247 eDiscovery214213464.PDF
8DF92926-20A9-4BE8-A11A-0BCB2B868A31    2021-07-27 16:42:13.247 eDiscovery2142134641.png
8DF92926-20A9-4BE8-A11A-0BCB2B868A31    2021-07-27 16:42:13.247 eDiscovery21421346410.png
8DF92926-20A9-4BE8-A11A-0BCB2B868A31    2021-07-27 16:42:13.247 eDiscovery21421346411.png
8DF92926-20A9-4BE8-A11A-0BCB2B868A31    2021-07-27 16:42:13.247 eDiscovery21421346412.png
8DF92926-20A9-4BE8-A11A-0BCB2B868A31    2021-07-27 16:42:13.247 eDiscovery21421346413.png
8DF92926-20A9-4BE8-A11A-0BCB2B868A31    2021-07-27 16:42:13.247 eDiscovery21421346414.png
8DF92926-20A9-4BE8-A11A-0BCB2B868A31    2021-07-27 16:42:13.247 eDiscovery21421346415.png
8DF92926-20A9-4BE8-A11A-0BCB2B868A31    2021-07-27 16:42:13.247 eDiscovery21421346416.png
8DF92926-20A9-4BE8-A11A-0BCB2B868A31    2021-07-27 16:42:13.247 eDiscovery2142134642.png
8DF92926-20A9-4BE8-A11A-0BCB2B868A31    2021-07-27 16:42:13.247 eDiscovery2142134643.png
8DF92926-20A9-4BE8-A11A-0BCB2B868A31    2021-07-27 16:42:13.247 eDiscovery2142134644.png
8DF92926-20A9-4BE8-A11A-0BCB2B868A31    2021-07-27 16:42:13.247 eDiscovery2142134645.png
8DF92926-20A9-4BE8-A11A-0BCB2B868A31    2021-07-27 16:42:13.247 eDiscovery2142134646.png
8DF92926-20A9-4BE8-A11A-0BCB2B868A31    2021-07-27 16:42:13.247 eDiscovery2142134647.png
8DF92926-20A9-4BE8-A11A-0BCB2B868A31    2021-07-27 16:42:13.247 eDiscovery2142134648.png
8DF92926-20A9-4BE8-A11A-0BCB2B868A31    2021-07-27 16:42:13.247 eDiscovery2142134649.png


SELECT COUNT(tf.id) AS cnt
            ,SUBSTRING(REPLACE(a.FileName, '.png', ''), 0, LEN(REPLACE(a.FileName, '.png', ''))) AS [FileName]
        FROM TrainingForm tf
        INNER JOIN Attachment a ON tf.Id = a.FormId
        WHERE a.FileName LIKE '%.png'
            AND datediff(dd, tf.CreatedOn, getdate()) < 60
        GROUP BY tf.id          ,a.FileName
```

And the results of this you see are TWO values not one because of the double digit.

```
1   eDiscovery214213464
1   eDiscovery2142134641
1   eDiscovery2142134641
1   eDiscovery2142134641
1   eDiscovery2142134641
1   eDiscovery2142134641
1   eDiscovery2142134641
1   eDiscovery2142134641
1   eDiscovery214213464
1   eDiscovery214213464
1   eDiscovery214213464
1   eDiscovery214213464
1   eDiscovery214213464
1   eDiscovery214213464
1   eDiscovery214213464
1   eDiscovery214213464
```

Comment: Why do some `pdfs` share the same file id??? Each pdf, if it had it's own unique id would be much easier to check against the data. ie. This id `5BB4D0AB-A8B9-436D-BDDB-00929A401F6` has two different pdfs - `Receipt215800891.pdf` and `onepagethi215843940.pdf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming you always have .pdf data, but the .png may not convert as mentioned**:

```
SELECT tf.id, tf.CreatedOn, a.FileName
FROM TrainingForm tf 
INNER JOIN Attachment a 
ON tf.Id = a.FormId
inner join
(
    --select the id and filename of items that have a COUNT < 2
    --ie. has a pdf but not a png
    SELECT x.id, x.FileName
    FROM
    (
        --union together groups of pdfs and pngs
        SELECT tf.id, REPLACE(a.FileName, '.pdf', '') AS [FileName]
        FROM TrainingForm tf
        INNER JOIN Attachment a 
        ON tf.Id = a.FormId
        where a.FileName like '%.pdf'
        group by tf.id, a.FileName
        UNION ALL
        select a.id, a.filename 
        from
        (
            SELECT b.[id], REPLACE(pdfs.[filename], '.pdf', '') AS [FileName] 
            FROM
            (
                SELECT tf.id
                FROM TrainingForm tf
                INNER JOIN Attachment a 
                ON tf.Id = a.FormId
                where a.FileName like '%.png'
                group by tf.id
            ) as b
            inner join Attachment as pdfs
            on b.[id] = pdfs.[Formid]
            where pdfs.[filename] like '%.pdf'
        ) as a
        inner join Attachment as f
        on f.Formid = a.id
        where CHARINDEX(REPLACE(a.filename, '.pdf', ''), f.filename) > 0 and f.filename like '%.png'
        group by a.id, a.filename
    ) as x
    group by x.id, x.FileName
    having COUNT(x.id) < 2
) as z
ON z.id = tf.id and a.FileName = z.FileName + '.pdf'
group by tf.id, tf.CreatedOn, a.FileName
ORDER BY tf.CreatedOn DESC
```

Comment: thanks.. that got me started.. I think a problem is a number is appended on the converted  filenames so the PDF/PNG names do not match exactly.. Trying to figure out a work around .. Can't just use the guId since sometimes a form has more than one attachment... So I think I would need to somehow remove that appended number on the PNG file.. Trying to figure that out..

Comment: Yes. When the user uploads a jpg/png/gif then I just leave it alone. The main point is about the PDF uploads and verifying a match/no match with the PNG converted file... I added you new code it is almost there.. See edit.

Comment: The query as is doesn't work.. For example it returns FW_-[EXTER214627673.pdf which does not have a PNG file.. But it got me on the right path.. So working on it now..

Comment: ok.. finally! got it working.. you are a genius!

Comment: @punkouter Awesome!! Good job. Glad I could help.

Comment: SQL Fiddle Update: [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cf82f/8)